# getting corresponding column information with groupby based on condition

Tags: pandas

Current dataframe looks like :

```
Group      amount      uniqueID        status
  A          100          A32          Success
  A          120          B33           Failed
  A          80           C44           Failed
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Group      amount      uniqueID        status
  A          120          B33           Failed
```

From the group it should pick the highest amount value and its respective uniqueID & status.

I have tried below code for getting the maximum amount value , how can we fetch its corresponding rows i.e. UniqueID and status

```
df_sorted = df.groupby(['Group']).agg({'amount': [np.max]})
```

Comment: `df.sort_values(['Group', 'amount']).drop_duplicates('Group',keep='last')`.

Comment: A sort is going to be `O(nlogn)`, you can use `idxmax` `df.iloc[df["amount"].idxmax()]` `groupby` first if you need it per `Group`

Comment: `idxmax` could help with a groupby

Answer (score 0):

```
>> pdf1

Group   amount  uniqueID    status
0   A   100     A32       Success
1   A   120     B33       Failed
2   A   80      C44       Failed

pdf2 = pdf1.groupby("Group").max("amount").reset_index()

>> pdf2
    Group   amount
0    A       120

>> pd.merge(pdf1, pdf2, on=["Group", "amount"])

    Group   amount  uniqueID    status
0   A         120   B33         Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `sort_values` with `groupby.tail`.

```
df.sort_values('amount').groupby('Group').tail(1)

  Group  amount uniqueID  status
1     A     120      B33  Failed
```